# jQuery's incoming data event handler

Tags: php, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am writing a PHP code to ping a computer from my server. The code is simple but I think the browser is caching the incoming data:

run.php

```
<?php

    for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        $host = '127.0.0.1'; 
        $port = 80; 
        $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
        if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
            // It worked 
            echo "yes, you can access $ip from this server<BR>";
            sleep(1);
        } else {
            // It didn't work 
            echo "nope, you cannot access $ip from this server<BR>";
        } 
        fclose($fp);
    }
    
?>
```

index.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'run.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.ping-data').append(data);
        }
    });
</script>
Ping data:
<div class="ping-data" style="border: 1px solid #9f9f9f; width: 600px; min-height: 400px;"></div>
```

But when I run the code index.php, it waits and echos the whole data once, instead of printing one line of ping per second. How can I catch this event and print the data whenever a line of data is sent?

Comment: create a time out on js instead of php.

Comment: i added timeout:1 and it didn't work!

Comment: i'm assuming `timeout:1` is added to ajax function. That will only delay the call of run.php for 1/1000 of a second

Answer (score 3):

you need to remove the sleep/for from php and create a function in js to intervally ping the server like:

```
var interval = setInterval(ping, 1000);
var times = 0;
var timestorun = 10;
function ping(){
    if(times < timestorun){
        times++;
    }else{
        clearInterval(interval);
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'run.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.ping-data').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The only potential issue with this, in theory, is that e.g. the result of the second ping could be returned before the result of the first ping, due to some sort of network delay (affecting the first ping) between your server running PHP and the browser. This has nothing to do with the pinging and only to do with the AJAX data communication. But in practice since there's a 1 second timeout it's extremely unlikely that that would be an issue in this case.

Comment: in that case if the user wants can use `setTimeout(ping, 10)` in the success function instead of using `setInterval` and just `ping()` for the first line.

Comment: What if I want to use exec("ping") and do not use java script's fixed intervals? I mean, I want to listen to the server and whenever it sends a line of data, I receive and echo it. In other words, I want the server to emit an event and the client handles that event.

Comment: @emab You could look into WebSockets. There are nice abstraction libraries that handle cross-browser issues, such as [socket.io](http://socket.io/). My initial impression is that that's overkill for this simple case.

Comment: @MattBrowne I was just about to mention websockets, but I don't have any experience with it but It looks like it would be better for a live communication.

Comment: @MattBrowne is it possible to use socket.io in php? I thought it is just for nodejs

Comment: @Class I have the experience in nodejs, but I don't know how to use it in php or other cgi languages

Comment: socket.io/nodejs is are javascript libraries to communicate with your server not the other way around. At least as far as I know.

Comment: socket.io is for true 2-way communication; that's what WebSocket's are all about. But you're right, I forgot about the fact that socket.io doesn't have a PHP version. There's another library that does, let me find the link...

Comment: If you feel the question along with the comments has answered or pointed you to the right way then do so.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove loop from PHP file so it executes request only once and add loop to client side (Javascript).

Comment: Yes, use the `setInterval` function in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Class's answer, I recommend adding the `cache` parameter to the ajax call in order to avoid browser side caching:

```
var interval = setInterval(ping, 1000);
var times = 0;
var timestorun = 10;
function ping(){
    if(times < timestorun){
        times++;
    }else{
        clearInterval(interval);
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'run.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.ping-data').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

See also [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I think you failed to copy and paste something correctly...I was expecting to see `cache: false` somewhere.

Comment: I thought about making a edit to your question, to add cache part. It would be kinda ironic wouldn't it?

Comment: @Class I can make the edit, but I tried adding cache: false (not with your suggestion)